# Sony Vaio VPC-EH1S0E bluetooth and num lock

Tags: bluetooth, vaio, numlock

**Notebook:** Sony Vaio VPC-EH1S0E
**Ram:** 4GB
**Graphics:** Intel HD3000
**Cpu:** Intel Core i5-2410m

I've got 2 problems:

1) i've always the bluetooth on when i boot or reboot. I want to turn it off (i don't use bluetooth)

2) i've always the num lock off when i boot or reboot. I wanto to have it on **forever**

Comment: For the bluetooth thing you may want to check your BIOS settings. Mine provides an option to always keep Bluetooth off.

Comment: there aren't any option in my bios :(

Answer (score 1):

There are two AskUbuntu Questions with good answers which should look at to resolve your query:

1. [How do you start-up in the login screen with Num Lock on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781/how-do-you-start-up-in-the-login-screen-with-num-lock-on)
2. [Can I default Bluetooth to off on my laptop Lenovo T61](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2567/can-i-default-bluetooth-to-off-on-my-laptop-lenovo-t61)

Comment: but i have lightdm not gdm :(

Answer (score 1):

I've solved!
For bluetooth i've add this line to **/etc/rc.local**:

`rfkill block bluetooth`

and for numlock i've installed numlockx and then i've added these lines to **/etc/X11/Xsession**:

`if [ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ]; then

      /usr/bin/numlockx on

fi`